# Passing the model's attribute to collectionOptions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

How can i pass the model's attribute to collectionOptions? When i try to pass param0 like that, then `this` is referenced to `window` instead to `MyModel` instance:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    defaults: {
        param0: null,
    },
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'others',
            relatedModel: 'OtherModel',
            collectionType: 'OtherModelCollection',
            collectionOptions: {param0: this.get('param0')}
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#collectionoptions):

> **collectionOptions**
>
> Value: an options hash or a function that accepts an instance of a `Backbone.Relational` Model and returns an option hash.

So just use a function instead of an object literal:

```
collectionOptions: function(m) {
    return {
        param0: m.get('param0')
    };
}
```

This "object or function" pattern is fairly common in the Backbone world, for example, [`Model#defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) behaves the same way.